# Cant retrieve information from table in ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Can't find why the object I'm supposed to retrieve from database is always empty, despite the fact that the table has 3 elements. In the view, `Model.Count` is always == 0. New to dotnet, stuck for hours.

What I did :

- connection string in `app.config`
- connection string in `web.config`

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="masterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-K74JGDL\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="DBModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1   .msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-K74JGDL\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=core2DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

- restart SQL Server
- Controller seems to know about my tables since it autocomplete tables and keys.

Posts.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public partial class Posts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Post_owner { get; set; }
        public string Post_content { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Post_like_count { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model1.Context.Cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class DBModel : DbContext
    {
        public DBModel() : base("DBModel")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           /* Database.SetInitializer<DBModel>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);*/
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In PostController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Post
        public ActionResult Index() 
        {
            var context = new DBModel();
            
            List<Posts> postsList = new List<Posts>();

            if (!context.Posts.Any())
            {
              /*  postsList = 3;*/
            }

            postsList = context.Posts.ToList();

            /*  using (var context = new DBModel())
              {
                  postsList = context.Posts.ToList(); 

              }*/

            return View(postsList);
        }
    }
}
```

and the view is (Index.cshtml) :

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Data.Posts>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Hello Peyo</h2>
<div>@Model</div>


@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <div><span>Nom: </span><span>@post.Post_content</span></div>
}

<span>Hello again</span>
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Does behavior change if you remove the spaces in this part of the connection string? `.../Model1   .msl;p...`

Comment: Same behavior after removing the spaces in the connection string. I have no error messages in vscode output, nor in browser console...

Comment: I don't know the details of each version of EF so I don't know if this works for you but if so what does this return at runtime if you put this code in the controller after you create the context? `context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;`

Comment: I dont know how to log in brower console or output from vscode. Kind of confuse. Any tips on that before ?

Comment: Can't you just debug it?